# MYSQL Order by and Group by

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have this

```
SELECT type, extra_id, COUNT(*) AS count, id 
FROM `notifications` 
WHERE `receiver_id` = '".$this->user_id."' 
    AND `read` = '0' 
GROUP BY type, extra_id 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

But this only orders by the first found result in the database as that's what is taken when i SELECT id. how can i make this so it takes the last found ID from `notifications` to use in the SELECT **id**?

Comment: Can we see some schema? Also you should not `SELECT` any columns which you're not aggregating (`id`).

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: The issue is he is grouping the query.  Each row has multiple `id`s, but only one can be shown.  MySQL shows the 1st value in this case.

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT(id)` and then use PHP to get the last one.

Comment: Yeah thats right @Rocket Could you give me a example of it? I am still a tad confused.

Comment: @user1527354: `GROUP_CONCAT` would return a string of all the ids separated by commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select `MAX(id)` instead of `id`:

```sql
SELECT type, extra_id, COUNT(*) AS count, MAX(id) AS max_id
FROM `notifications` 
WHERE `receiver_id` = '".$this->user_id."' 
    AND `read` = '0' 
GROUP BY type, extra_id 
ORDER BY max_id DESC
```